# How to distinguish logical or parameters in a cucumber step?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Let say I have the following step definition header for Ruby 2.3:

```
When (/^I update user group "([^"]*)" with (groups|users)?$/) do |group_name, type, params|
```

How do I use the "type" variable to distinguish between the case of using groups or users? What is the type of "type"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in cucumber all the parameters are String, so you must to convert them with reflexion to the type you want.

> When Cucumber matches a Step against a pattern in a Step Definition,
>   it passes the value of all the capture groups to the Step Definition's
>   arguments.
>
> Capture groups are strings (even when they match digits like \d+). For
>   statically typed languages, Cucumber will automatically transform
>   those strings into the appropriate type. For dynamically typed
>   languages, no transformation happens by default, as there is no type
>   information.

reference https://cucumber.io/docs/reference